# Halachic definition of "full" (sated)

Tags: blessing, food, shiurim-measurements, bentching, meal-seudah

I was reading this:

> After the fact (if one ate between 8 Kezayitim and a definite meal), if one is not full make Al HaMichya and if one is full make Birkat HaMazon, yet, in such a case it’s preferable to hear Birkat HaMazon (from someone who’s obligated to make Birkat HaMazon) or to eat bread (making HaMotzei and Birkat HaMazon).

How full is "full"? If my hunger was slaked, but I could eat more, am I "full"?

Comment: Can you edit to clarify where you read it (mostly because you're asking readers to interpret someone's words and it helps to know whose, but also as a courtesy to the author) and to include a bit of context: specifically, *what food* is under discussion as having been eaten?

Comment: Is this your source? http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Making_a_meal_on_Mezonot&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile#Amount_of_a_meal_when_Pas_Haba_Bekisnin_is_eaten_alone

Comment: Besides listing the source, just viewing the quote, there's a major initial question. The 1st sentence says 8 kezetim. If it's 8 olive sizes of mezonot (cakes, pizza, etc.) I am pretty sure that he would be required to wash hands first and say Hamotzi and end with Birkat Hamazon, anyway. I Should add, that the last sentence is a bit puzzling. In a sense, it implies starting a new meal, which seems to negate the idea that you already had a meal beforehand. If that's the case, why not just eat bread to start?